# Which is the precise definition of the POSIX Regex [:alpha:] character class?

Tags: regex, posix

It is not clear to me if the POSIX `[:alpha:]` Regex character class is strictly equivalent to Regex expression `[a-zA-Z]` in all locales or character sets, or if it also includes accented characters if the locale or character set in question allows for accented characters.

The spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html only mentions that it should be supported by all locales, but not what it includes.

Is there any authoritative place in which the exact meaning of the `[:alpha:]` character class is clearly defined?

Comment: The reference you linked seems to date from 2004, and it links to a much newer version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[2013 spec, 9.3.5.7](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html):

> In the POSIX locale, a range expression represents the set of
>   collating elements that fall between two elements in the collation
>   sequence, inclusive. *In other locales, a range expression has
>   unspecified behavior: strictly conforming applications shall not rely
>   on whether the range expression is valid, or on the set of collating
>   elements matched.*

(Emphasis added.)

So, outside the POSIX locale, `[a-zA-Z]`, strictly speaking, isn't even
defined. (Of course, since these are all ASCII characters, in practice
I would expect it to mean the same thing in any locale; but consider
EBCDIC, where those characters aren't even contiguous. So there could
be exceptions.)

The exact meaning of `[:alpha:]` depends on locale, and there are many,
many locales, defined by various entities. I certainly wouldn't make
any assumptions about what `[:alpha:]` did or did not contain in any
locale other than POSIX.

Comment: Well-known counterexamples for `A-Z` include case-insensitive collations where 25 of the lowercase letters are included, based on either an `AaBb...YyZ` range or an `AbB..yYzZ` range, but that should not affect `A-Za-z`, and languages where `z` comes somewhere between `s` and `t` (Estonian, IIRC), which should. Of course other letters (possibly accented versions) are included in many locales as well.

Comment: Just for clarificartion in my question, was referring to POSIX as in "POSIX Regex flavor", not really the POSIX locale.  Our tool has a Regex engine which is highly inspired in POSIX Regex ERE and we wanted to check if our interpretation of what [:alpha:] means is consistent with the expectations of the guys who actually wrote the POSIX Regex spec.

Comment: @Pep: **By specification**, POSIX regex is dependent on the locale settings. However, implementation may implement only the regex syntax without support for locale, and this is where you need to consult the exact documentation of the regex library which provides the functionality.

Comment: By the way, `[a-z]` can match `ñ` in `piñatas`, if you set  `LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"` on Cygwin. Test code `[[ "piñatas" =~ ([a-z]*) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"`

Comment: @nhahtdh Actually we wrote a few years ago the Regex library we are using, and I wanted to double-check if there was any precise expectation for [:alpha:].  If, according to the spec, anything goes, then I guess we are fine in our library with regards to the spec.